# Why do search results differ on YouTube on iPad compared to PC?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web

When I search for some songs on YouTube on iPad I get different results compared to Web Based PC. Also sometimes websites seem to updated on PC but the iPad doesn't when I log on to both the websites at the same time!

Please kindly clarify how.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the difference in search and using habits of youtube between your ipad and your pc causes those devices to belong in two separated [filter bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble). Try to delete cookies and clear cache on both devices.

greetings

Answer (score 1):

For YouTube, this is mainly due to copyrighted material found in the videos.

Most of the recording companies will allow YouTube to keep videos that includes of their contents **if** YouTube share revenues from ads on that video.

So the difference with your PC and your iPad is: One is a monetized platform and the other isn't (if you still use the stock app or the web browser). So if a YouTube video can't comply to the rules set by recording companies (for example) it will not show up in the results on an iPad.

Here's the list of monetized platforms vs non-monetized platforms I found [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2453875?hl=en).

> The following platforms are examples of platforms we consider monetized:

```
- www.youtube.com
- YouTube app on Android and iOS
- YouTube app on TVs including Xbox, Google TV, PlayStation 3, and Chromecast
- m.youtube.com accessed from most smartphones
```

> In addition to monetized platforms mentioned above, "all platforms" include but are not limited to the following:

```
- YouTube app pre-installed on iOS 5 and below
- YouTube app on Apple TV
- YouTube legacy apps on feature phones and TVs
- m.youtube.com accessed from feature phones
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two answers above, sometimes the uploader of the video explicitly doesn't allow the video to be accessed on mobile devices.